# Find H'(x), Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f$ be continuous on $I = [a, b]$ and let $H: I \to \Bbb{R}$ be defined by $H(x) = \int_x^b f(t) dt, x \in I$. Find H'(x).

I've always seen the FTOC Part 1 written as $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt, x \in I$, in which the derivative would simply by f(t), and I've never considered what happens if I go from x to b instead until now. What is different when the limits are changed?

Comment: You would get a 'minus' sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that
$$ H(x) = \int_a^b f(t)\,dt - \int_a^x f(t)\,dt
$$
the first term is constant and thus has $0$ derivative.

Another approach would be
$$ H(x) = \int_x^b f(t)\,dt = -\int_b^x f(t)\,dt
$$

Answer (score 0):

Going back to fundamentals,
since
$H(x) = \int_x^b f(t) dt$,

$\begin{array}\\
H(x+h)-H(x)
&=\int_{x+h}^b f(t) dt-\int_x^b f(t) dt\\
&=\int_{x+h}^b f(t) dt-(\int_x^{x+h} f(t) dt+\int_{x+h}^b f(t) dt)\\
&=-\int_x^{x+h} f(t) dt
\qquad\text{(this is where the "-" comes from)}\\
\text{so}\\
\frac{H(x+h)-H(x)}{h}
&=-\frac1{h}\int_x^{x+h} f(t) dt\\
&\to -f(x)
\text{ as } h \to 0\\
\end{array}
$